# Minor changes on theme per subdomain - same contents

Tags: themes, child-theme

I would like to run a knowledge base based on wordpress, main URL will be docs.product.com but i would like to see minor changes on the theme when url is different, f.e other.product.com, other2.product.com and so on.

Changes will be colours or logos.

What is the best approach? multisite, network, child themes...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use multisite with child theme with some customization based on `site_ID`.

```
E.g if(get_current_blog_id() == 1) { condition } else { condition }
```